# db active records

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to get some data from my database with active records,and I'm having the following problem. I wanna learn how to do it with active records since after this code i have a ton of joins and other stuff. Otherwise I would write a normal query.

```
        $this->db->where("sa.country", $country);


         // I NEED TO OPEN BRACKETS HERE SO THAT I CAN GET THE LANGUAGES IF THERE IS DATA IN ONE OF THE ARRAYS


        if (isset($lid[0]))$this->db->where("sa.lang", $lid[0]);
        if (isset($lid[1]))$this->db->or_where("sa.lang", $lid[1]);
        if (isset($lid[2]))$this->db->or_where("sa.lang", $lid[2]);
        if (isset($lid[3]))$this->db->or_where("sa.lang", $lid[3]);
        if (isset($lid[4]))$this->db->or_where("sa.lang", $lid[4]);


        //AND CLOSE THEM HERE
```

My goal is to get a specific country from db, with the corresponding languages that are in the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `WHERE...IN...`! See help [about 'where in'](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

With ActiveRecord:

```
$this->db->where_in("sa.lang",$lid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```php
$this->db->where("sa.country", $country);

// loop through *set* languages
foreach($lid as $item)
{
    $this->db->where('sa.lang', $item);
}

// will return a query object
return $this->db->get('my_table');
```

Comment: nope, the problem is not in the arrays, the question is about the SQL expression.

Comment: "My goal is to get a specific country from db, with the corresponding languages that are in the arrays."

I think what you're trying to do is say ```WHERE sa.country = $country AND (sa.lang=language1 OR sa.lang=language2 /* etc... */)``` right?

Comment: exactly. Your example produces the following query `WHERE sa.country = $country AND sa.lang=language1 AND sa.lang=language2 /* etc... */)`

Comment: check out the answer below, it is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem for anyone interested in the solution.

```
$this->db->where("(`sa`.`lang` = '$lid[0]' OR `sa`.`lang` = '$lid[1]' OR `sa`.`lang` = '$lid[2]' OR `sa`.`lang` = '$lid[3]' OR `sa`.`lang` = '$lid[4]')");
```

Comment: That's a bad solution and prone to SQL injections (unless you validate input somewhere before this part). You should check the `where_in()` method from the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The array comes from the db as i said in the post so i believe there can't be an injection. Besides when you generate input fields using the codeigniter's helpers with enabled XSS, that should take care of sql injection. no?

Comment: If you see the changelog for CI you will notice that XSS cleaning has been updated (for bugs and improvements) several times. You shouldn't rely on this feature alone. Always use prepared statements or at least escape your dynamic input (no matter where it comes from) before using it in your databases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Repox. Much appreciated!